# How do I know that the image shown is cached?

Tags: php, caching

I am using timThumb that has a cache engine. As the script/tutorials say, you have to have a cache file with permission 0777. This is what I have already.

When an image is viewed in the page, using the below

```
timthumb.php?src=http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg
```

it creates a `9c9313eced007f38eb59791dad91edb1.jpg` file in the cache folder.

I checked the image and it is the same I saw. On my next refresh, I view the page source and I get again

`timthumb.php?src=http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg` instead of the cached image.

My question is, shouldn't show a `domain.com/9c9313eced007f38eb59791dad91edb1.jpg` ?

This is the code I use http://codepad.org/pVzET9Dv ( It is a modified version to accept all domains )

Note: I tried it also with the official release, but again the same. Maybe it's how cache works, I don't know.. But if is so, how can I check that what I saw is the cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong idea about the concept of caching here.

Notice that when a file is in the `cache_dir`, php checks whether the user has sent him the header `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE`.

If the browser sends this header, then this means that the browser has a local copy of this file which has had a `Last-Modified` value of `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` when it was downloaded.

Now, if this date is the really the last modification date of the image, the server sends the header `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`.

Notice the check in function `show_cache_file`.

---

One more thing, it seems php is re-sizing the image and saving the re-sized image in its own cache folder. So in this way, the re-sizing process is not repeated again.

---

I am not aware whether there is a browser that allows you to know if a displayed image is fetched from cache or downloaded. Anyway this is irrelevant since the user must be sure that it is the most recent image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does cache speed up page loading ? Because I can't see any difference with cache on or off.

Comment: yes of course "less load on the server because it will not send all images" "faster load time on client because it will not download all images"

Comment: Isn't there any possible way of knowing if it cached or downloaded? With a script or something...

Comment: on server side: if this is executed `if ( $if_modified_since == $gmdate_mod ) {
                header( "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified" );
                exit;
            }`, then cached version of image is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The URL `timthumb.php?src=http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg`
 will not change.  The logic of the script is like this:

---

I have been given a URL to an image "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg"

Do I have a cached copy on disk that is not expired?

NO: go retrive the image from "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg", write it to cache, then display it.

YES: read the file from the disk and display it.

---

So even though you are saying the image is here (through the query string parameter src=) "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg" it doesn't mean the script actually retrieves it from there every time.

I would say the fact that your permissions are correct and cache files are being written to the folder, that is verification enough it is working.

Any kind of verification beyond this would be kind of a waste of time.

Comment: How does the script know that image saved in cache folder like `9c9313eced007f38eb59791dad91edb1.jpg` is the one to show in the right place? I do not mean that the script is not working, it is a knowledge question.

Comment: 9c9313eced007f38eb59791dad91edb1 is an md5 sum of the src param passed in the query string.  it is calculated from the url you are giving it - so if you give it the same url twice, this calculation is the same both times.  It's like how storing a hashed password works.